# What is a good, free ad server?

Tags: advertising, banners

Right now I am using OpenX. But over the years it got more and more bloated. I barely use 10% of its functionality. What are the alternatives and what is it that makes them good?

I need:

- image banners
- html banners
- stats on impressions and clicks
- even distribution of booked impressions over the booked time (like max 10000 impressions per day for 10 days)
- weekly stats per email (for admin and for customer)

Please list one ad server per answer for easier ranking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about Google DFP - it nearly meets all your requirements (except for sending weekly stats) and you don't have to worry about hosting, upgrades, etc.

Here's a [quick tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dfp-tutorial/14099/) to help you get started.

Comment: Looks pretty good. I guess I will have to play with it a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Google AdWords](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97526) ?

Comment: That is an advertiser, not an ad server.

Comment: No, people who buy ads on AdWords/AdSense are advertisers. AdWords is an ad network, which also makes them an ad server (they store and serve up ads).

Comment: An ad server is a piece of software in the context of this question. Adsense would be an advertiser. I do not look for a company that serves ads. I thought the question makes that clear.

Comment: Ever heard of SaaS?

Answer (score 1):

openX is very nice. I have used it in the past. [openX](http://www.openx.org/)

Comment: OpenX is what I use now, but I am looking for an alternative (as stated in my question)...